# prove the chordal distance is: $d(x,y)=\frac{2|z-z'|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}\sqrt{1+|z'|^2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $P(x,y,z)$ and $P'(x,y,z)$ two points in S, where
$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ the chordal distance is the lenght of $P$ with $P'$. If $P$ correspond to $z$ and $P'$ with $z'$ prove the chordal distance is:

$$d(x,y)=\frac{2|z-z'|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}\sqrt{1+|z'|^2}}$$

**My attempt:**

Let $f:C_\infty\rightarrow S$ such that $f(z)=(\frac{2x}{|z|^2+1},\frac{2y}{|z|^2+1},\frac{|z|^2-1}{|z|^2+1})$

Note that $d(P,P')=d(f(z),f(z'))=d(z,z')$

Here i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Comment: In title should be $+$ between terms under second radical in denominator, not $-.$

Comment: You should explain what the chordal metric is. As it is, your question is very confusing. You use $x,y,z$ as the coordinates of points of $S$, but the same symbols occur in your formula, having of course a completety different meaning. Clarify notation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in S$ correspond to $z = (x, y) \in \hat{\mathbb C}$
and $(x_1', x_2', x_3') \in S$ correspond to $z' = (x', y') \in \hat {\mathbb C}$

Then $d(z, z') = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_1')^2 + (x_2 - x_2')^2 + (x_3 - x_3')^2} = \sqrt{2 - 2(x_1 x_1' + x_2 x_2' + x_3 x_3')}$

Next note that

$x_1 x_1' + x_2 x_2' + x_3 x_3' = 1 - \frac{2|z - z'|^2}{(1+|z|^2)(1+|z'|^2)}$

and you are done!

[Some details:

$\displaystyle x_1 = \frac{z + \bar{z}}{1 +|z|^2}$

$\displaystyle x_2 = \frac{z - \bar{z}}{i(1 +|z|^2)}$

$\displaystyle x_3 = \frac{-1 +|z|^2}{1 + |z|^2}$

$\displaystyle x_1 x_1' + x_2 x_2' + x_3 x_3'$

$\displaystyle = \frac{(z + \bar{z})(z'+ \bar{z'}) − (z - \bar{z})(z' - \bar{z'})
+ (|z|^2 − 1)(|z'|^2 − 1)}{(1+|z|^2)(1+|z'|^2)}$

$\displaystyle =1 - \frac{2|z - z'|^2}{(1+|z|^2)(1+|z'|^2)}$
]