# Question about the stereographic projection. How to find the arc of great circle of the stereographic sphere S.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

Let $z$, $w$ be complex numbers and let $P(z)$, $P(w)$ be the corresponding
points on the sphere $S$, associated to $z$, $w$ via the stereographic projection.
Find the length of the arc of the great circle lying on $S$ and joining $P(z)$ to
$P(w)$.

I started to consider the arc of the center should be the greatest length. But I'm so confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Euclidean distance between the projections $P(z)$, $P(w)$ onto the sphere $S$ is the “chordal distance” of $z$ and $w$ and can be computed as
$$
 d(z, w) = \frac{2|z-w|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}\sqrt{1+|w|^2}} \, ,
$$
see for example

- [prove the chordal distance is: $d(x,y)=\frac{2|z-z'|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}\sqrt{1+|z'|^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447214/prove-the-chordal-distance-is-dx-y-frac2z-z-sqrt1z2-sqrt1z),
- [Riemann sphere](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) on Encyclopedia of Mathematics.

The length  $L$ of the arc joining $P(z)$ and $P(w)$ is equal to the angle between the vectors from the origin to $P(z)$ and $P(w)$ respectively, so that
$$
 \sin \frac{L}{2} = \frac 12 \|P(z)-P(w)\| = \frac{|z-w|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}\sqrt{1+|w|^2}} 
$$
or
$$
 L = 2 \arcsin \left( \frac{|z-w|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}\sqrt{1+|w|^2}} \right)\, .
$$